# Hive CLI: what are the possible exit codes and their meanings?

Tags: shell, command-line-interface, hive

I'm working on a shell script that uses the Hive CLI client to execute some HQL scripts. Sometimes these calls can generate an Exception, and in my script, I have to check for when that happens.

I'm having a hard time finding any documentation whatsoever on the CLI client. I can't find anything on [hive.apache.org](http://hive.apache.org) OR the [Wiki](https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/Hive/Home), and pertinent Google searches don't return anything useful either.

Can anyone provide me with a list of possible exit codes for the Hive CLI and their meanings?

Answer (score -2):

Why not use the hive thrift api instead? Then you get exceptions returned with proper messages.

In ruby it's as simple as:

```
require 'rubygems'
require 'rbhive'


RBHive.connect(host, port) do |connection|
    begin
        connection.fetch("select * from table1") #this throws various exceptions
    rescue Exception => ex
        puts "oh no! An error: #{ex.message}"
    end
end
```